# LM2902 as a unity-gain amplifer failure

Tags: operational-amplifier

I was using a LM2902 as a unity-gain amplifier, and i assumed that it needed no additional components to work (obviously poor choice of IC).

I shorted Vo to the negative input and inputted the voltage i wanted buffer on the positive input.

after it failed (it drew current from the positive input, and outputted nothing), i looked at the datasheet and the schematic for a Unity-Gain amplifier for this particular IC requires a capacitor and resistor.

[image: lm2902 datasheet schemantic]

DATASHEET : http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2902.pdf

PS:anyone mind recommending me a quad op-amp that i can use a unity-gain buffer to isolate measurements from 5v sensors. Vcc can be adjusted anywhere from 5v to 15v, temp range is -40c ~ 125C. Not sure what other specs are required.

EDIT: So I’ve had this prototype for about 2 months, and then it failed (it could have been degrading over time and failed, not sure).  The power comes from a 7808 that is powered from the cars battery (12v).  and here are the pictures of the actual device. i was not able to find any crossed wires, the device was rigidly attached to a case that should have prevented it moving and pushing wires together.

the 3 other Op-amps in the IC are fine. only 1 failed (blue wire).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Show us a photo of what you actually built. What did you use for a power supply?

Comment: Also, what range of input voltages are you applying?

Comment: It does not require a capacitor or resistor. Like the title says, parameters on datasheet were measured with the setup like in picture, with certain resistive and capacitance load. It must be something else that is wrong. What were your signal voltages and supply voltages?

Comment: edited original post. signal voltages is 0-5v supply voltages is 8v, coming from a 7808.

Comment: Did you touch the inputs ? It can be  ESD problem.

Comment: Nope, everything was going as normal. the op-amp was buffering the voltage from the sensor, the specific time of failure the sensor was operating in about the middle portion of its range (split 5v into 3 segments, and it was the middle).

Comment: What is the sensor?

Comment: It attaches to multiple sensors. One is a temp sensor, other is pressure and the last is a flow sensor. All output analog 0-5v signals. The pin the failed on the op amp was connected to the flow sensor

Answer (score 1):

No, Fig. 7 is not saying that the op-amp **needs** a resistor and capacitor as the load. Fig. 7 is simply showing the test circuit used to measure the slew rate and unity-gain bandwidth (Table 6.8).

If the device "drew current" on its non-inverting input then the op-amp is faulty, or you have wired it incorrectly.

Comment: It worked for 2 months, then failed. so must have been wired correctly, but its strange it only failed at one op-amp of the 4 on the IC.

Comment: "It worked for 2 months, then failed. so must have been wired correctly," then why rewire it?  Actually, if it only lasts for two months then there's a fault someplace.  This is an XY problem.  Instead of asking whether your proposed solution is correct, why don't you start a **new** question with the title "why did my op-amp fail after two months of operation".

Comment: That is literally my title, op-amp failed. And I don't think I stated anywhere that I rewired everything.

Comment: @haxxor No, your title says "**as a unity-gain amplifier** failure" which suggests that the op-amp is fully functional but the unity-gain **circuit** is incorrect. That's certainly what you indicated in your question.

Comment: my mistake, i'm a mechanical engineer and I was not aware that there even a difference between those 2 statements.